# images broken on meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, broken-image

I'm doing this Meteor course where an old version of Meteor is used and unsure of where to put files and folders. I have images in a public folder which is in my main folder and the following main.html client code

```
<head>
  <title>image_share</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Coursera!</h1>

  {{>images}}

</body>

<template name="images">
    {{#each images}}
        <img src="{{img_src}}" height="100" alt="{{img_alt}}" />
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

and the following client code main.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    console.log("I am the client");

var img_data = [
    {
        img_src:"image1.jpg",
        img_alt:"dental surgery"
    },

    {
        img_src:"image2.jpg",
        img_alt:"carribean night"
    },

    {
        img_src:"image3.jpg",
        img_alt:"full moon palm tree"
    },

];

Template.images.helpers({images:img_data});
}
```

My problem is only image1.jpg is appearing in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Your helpers should be functions:

```
Template.images.helpers({
    images:function() {
        return img_data;
    },
});
```

And in your template its good to explicitly reference to the data in the loop in context of "this":

```
{{#each images}}
    <img src="{{this.img_src}}" height="100" alt="{{this.img_alt}}" />
{{/each}}
```

"This" refers here to the current object in the array, you iterate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Made the changes you advised but still only image1 is showing in the browser window.

Comment: Names are correct, no typos or something? Paths are correct? Assuming your code, the images should be in the public folder wihtout any subfolders.

Comment: Double checked, trible checked... path and names are correct. Images in public folder and not subfolder.

Comment: What happes, if you replace `<img src="{{this.img_src}}" height="100" alt="{{this.img_alt}}" />` with `<div>{{this.img_src}}</div>` just to see, if the names are printed, as desired.

Comment: Yes, the image names are printed as image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg

Comment: So this is rather an html problem or a problem by the images themselfes. What happens if you change your img to `<img src="{{this.img_src}}" alt="{{this.img_alt}}" /><br>` ?

Comment: adding <br> puts every image on a new line. Do you suppose the images are too high res? I downloaded a image off the internet and its showing that image but sitll not image2 and image3.

Comment: What happens if you put a `/` in front of the `src` path? like `<img src="/{{this.img_src}}" />`